# Should we "borrow" questions from other UX forums and post them on UX.SE to drive traffic?

Tags: discussion, promotion

I was looking through the SE site stats and I noticed that UX.SE receives less than 3k of visits per day and we're behind topics like Skepticism, Physics, and Home Improvement. So I posted in the chat, and Erics [suggested reposting good UX questions from elsewhere](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3165911#3165911) and then linking OPs to here. These "borrowed" questions would need to be edited to conform to SE standards (which isn't much work usually).

I see some merits to this tactic but I'm concerned about ethics of blatantly posting links to SE and the potential flood of low-quality and open-ended questions as people start migrating here from LinkedIn & Quora.

What do you think? Should we start doing this?

Comment: I'd say if a question seems interesting *to you* go ahead and formulate it as a UX.SE question and ask, if we gain answers you feel the other site could benefit from, go ahead and toss a link in a comment/whatever over on the other site.

Answer (score 6):

Generating traffic works best when you add value, and adding value happens to be one of the things we do best when we provide great answers and great questions. So I think that if we were to do this, we should do it under the banner of wanting to add value, not wanting to drive traffic.

As such, if you think there's a question on another website which would benefit from exposure to the UX.SE community, then go ahead and ask it. A nice side-effect could be that we generate traffic as a result, but that shouldn't be the goal, because our ultimate goal isn't to drive traffic, it's to add value.

Comment: Also, the UX community here might reveal a better answer than is available on the "other" site.  I agree with Rahul, that the benefit of Stack Exchange sites is that they provide real value.  Traffic will come, if the value is here.